# How to make images appear when scrolling properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make two images appear in a "front-image" section when I scroll. When the user scrolls down, the images should behave as follows:

- top-image: must go down
- bottom-image: must go up

when the user scrolls up the behavior must be reversed.

What I've tried so far using a pinch of js to follow the scroll:

```js
  const frontImageSection = document.querySelector('.front-image');
  const topImage = document.querySelector('.top-image');
  const bottomImage = document.querySelector('.bottom-image');

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
    const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    const frontImageSectionTop = frontImageSection.offsetTop;
    const frontImageSectionHeight = frontImageSection.offsetHeight;

    const topImageOffset = (scrollPosition / frontImageSectionHeight) * 100;

    let bottomImageOffset = -((scrollPosition / frontImageSectionHeight) * 100);

    topImage.style.transform = `translateY(${topImageOffset}%)`;
    bottomImage.style.transform = `translateY(${bottomImageOffset}%)`;
  });
```

```css
  body {
    height: 300vh;
  }

  .front-image {
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 96.2px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .front-image .top-image,
  .front-image .bottom-image {
    position: fixed;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    width: 200px;
  }

  .front-image .top-image {
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
  }

  .front-image .bottom-image {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }

  .front-image .content picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 525px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="front-image">
    <div class="square-box"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 px-0">
          <div class="content">
            <picture>
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bTX82bl.jpeg" class="">
            </picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Vvy6Cfp/Pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-9158356.png" alt="Logo"
      class="top-image">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Vvy6Cfp/Pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-9158356.png" alt="Logo"
      class="bottom-image">
  </section>
</body>
```

but the behavior is quite bizarre and doesn't even seem smooth, also, the images should appear within the section, but for some reason they pop out I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i dont really get exactlly the results that you are looking to achive  ,can you explain more the way the two cats should move and the back image possition

Comment: yes of course, the rear image of the landscape remains fixed, when the user scrolls and reaches the image the cat present in the upper right part descends downwards, while the other cat on the left must rise from the bottom towards the top. I added a drawing to clarify the concept better: https://i.imgur.com/POCtUYS.png

Comment: Why don't you change cat's position to absolute instead of fixed?

Comment: Also set your transition as linear (not ease-in-out) and scroll-behavior: smooth; in .top-image and bottom-image

Comment: If you also remove the padding from your .front-image you won't have that 'overflowing cat' as offsetHeight takes into account padding

Comment: @Mehdi could you please show me a working example?

Comment: Just posted an answer with comments changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this. Now cats don't show when scrollposition is 0

```js
const frontImageSection = document.querySelector('.front-image');
const topImage = document.querySelector('.top-image');
const bottomImage = document.querySelector('.bottom-image');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {


  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  if(scrollPosition==0){
    topImage.style.opacity = 0;
    bottomImage.style.opacity = 0;
  }else{
    topImage.style.opacity = 1;
    bottomImage.style.opacity = 1;
  }
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const frontImageSectionTop = frontImageSection.offsetTop;
  const frontImageSectionHeight = frontImageSection.offsetHeight;

  const topImageOffset = (scrollPosition / frontImageSectionHeight) * 100;

  let bottomImageOffset = -((scrollPosition / frontImageSectionHeight) * 100);

  topImage.style.transform = `translateY(${topImageOffset}%)`;
  bottomImage.style.transform = `translateY(${bottomImageOffset}%)`;
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 300vh;
  }

  .front-image {
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    /* padding-top: 96.2px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; /* added smooth scroll*/
  }

  .front-image .top-image,
  .front-image .bottom-image{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; /* changed position to absolute*/
    transition: all 0.3s linear; /*changed transition to linear*/
    width: 200px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; /* added smooth scroll*/
  }

  .front-image .top-image {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
  }

  .front-image .bottom-image {
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }

  .front-image .content picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 525px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
    <section class="front-image">
        <div class="square-box"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 px-0">
              <div class="content">
                <picture>
                  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bTX82bl.jpeg" class="">
                </picture>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Vvy6Cfp/Pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-9158356.png" alt="Logo"
          class="top-image">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Vvy6Cfp/Pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-9158356.png" alt="Logo"
          class="bottom-image">
      </section>
```

Comment: thank you, this version seems to be more suitable for my needs. However, I'm noticing a problem in my javascript code, I'm pretty sure that the scroll functionality should only be triggered when scrolling over the section, otherwise the `translateY` property will be triggered before the user reaches the "front-image" section

Comment: Also just for your information there is an excellent css property that can avoid using javascript check this one also it might be interesting for you. It is animation using animation-timeline: view() or scroll() the animation will only be trigeered when scrolling or viewing section too

Comment: so there is a way to track the scroll property using css? I didn't know it

Comment: yes check this video it is really helpful video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UmzFk68Bwdk)

Answer (score 1):

You can change cat's position to absolute instead of fixed. Also set your transition as linear (not ease-in-out) and scroll-behavior: smooth; in .top-image and bottom-image. Also remove the padding from your .front-image and you won't have that 'overflowing cat' as offsetHeight takes into account padding.

```js
const frontImageSection = document.querySelector('.front-image');
const topImage = document.querySelector('.top-image');
const bottomImage = document.querySelector('.bottom-image');

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    topImage.style.opacity = 1;
    bottomImage.style.opacity = 1;

  const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const frontImageSectionTop = frontImageSection.offsetTop;
  const frontImageSectionHeight = frontImageSection.offsetHeight;

  const topImageOffset = (scrollPosition / frontImageSectionHeight) * 100;

  let bottomImageOffset = -((scrollPosition / frontImageSectionHeight) * 100);

  topImage.style.transform = `translateY(${topImageOffset}%)`;
  bottomImage.style.transform = `translateY(${bottomImageOffset}%)`;
});
```

```css
body {
    height: 300vh;
  }

  .front-image {
    top: 20%;
    position: relative;
    /* padding-top: 96.2px; */
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; /* added smooth scroll*/
  }

  .front-image .top-image,
  .front-image .bottom-image{
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute; /* changed position to absolute*/
    transition: all 0.3s linear; /*changed transition to linear*/
    width: 200px;
    scroll-behavior: smooth; /* added smooth scroll*/
  }

  .front-image .top-image {
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 10%;
  }

  .front-image .bottom-image {
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 10%;
  }

  .front-image .content picture img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 525px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<section class="front-image">
        <div class="square-box"></div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 px-0">
              <div class="content">
                <picture>
                  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/bTX82bl.jpeg" class="">
                </picture>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Vvy6Cfp/Pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-9158356.png" alt="Logo"
          class="top-image">
        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Vvy6Cfp/Pngtree-isolated-cat-on-white-background-9158356.png" alt="Logo"
          class="bottom-image">
      </section>
```

Comment: hi thanks you very much for the example, do you think there is a way to ensure that the images are not visible immediately but appear progressively when scrolling?

Comment: you mean the image appears on scroll yes of course. you can use opacity for that I am updating my code for you

Comment: you need for that to set images opacity to 0 set transition to all (not just transform) and then on scroll listener just set back opacity to 1. If this helped you you can accept the answer and/or upvote 

Comment: I am adding another answer where cats only show on scroll not before (at scrollposition 0), maybe you prefer this version

Comment: thank you, I will wait the other version

Comment: You very welcome, just posted the second version 